# Handling Null Associations with Pagination in Spring Data JPA for OneToMany and ManyToOne Relationships

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm working on a Spring Boot application using Spring Data JPA, and I am dealing with two entities: `Label` and `LabelSupplier`. These entities are connected via a `@ManyToOne` relationship from `LabelSupplier` to `Label`, and the inverse `@OneToMany` relationship from `Label` to `LabelSuppliers`. Here's the basic outline of the entities:

```java
@Entity
public class Label {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "label")
    private Set<LabelSupplier> labelSuppliers = new HashSet<>();
    // Additional fields and methods...
}

@Entity
public class LabelSupplier {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "label_id", nullable = true) // Notable for allowing nulls
    private Label label;
    // Additional fields and methods...
}
```

My application needs to support pagination when fetching `LabelSuppliers`, including those where the `label` might be `null`. Additionally, for `Labels` with no associated `LabelSuppliers`, I need to display them as having null suppliers.

I've successfully implemented basic pagination for fetching `LabelSuppliers`, but I'm struggling with integrating the requirement to show `Labels` with no suppliers, especially in a paginated context. My primary challenge is ensuring a consistent and intuitive presentation of this information, considering some `LabelSuppliers` might not be associated with a `Label` (null `label`), and some `Labels` might have no suppliers.

**Questions:**

1. How do I fetch `LabelSuppliers` with pagination, including those with a `null` associated `Label`, while ensuring performance and scalability?
2. What's the best strategy to include `Labels` with no suppliers in my paginated response? Ideally, this should be part of or easily integrable with the paginated list of suppliers.
3. Are there recommended patterns or practices in Spring Data JPA to handle this mixed requirement of pagination and null associations elegantly?

I am seeking guidance on structuring my queries, **with the Criteria API**, and how to architect my service layer or DTOs to accommodate these nuanced requirements.
Any examples, insights, or advice would be greatly appreciated.

I attempted to implement pagination for fetching LabelSupplier entities using the Criteria API in Hibernate 5. I managed to paginate the results for LabelSuppliers but had trouble incorporating those with a null associated Label. Specifically, my Criteria API query does not seem to correctly factor in LabelSuppliers without a linked Label. I was expecting to be able to query all LabelSuppliers, including those unlinked from a Label, in a paginated format, considering the total count accurately for UI display purposes.

**Please note,** suggestions to use `JoinType.RIGHT` in the criteria queries aren't applicable, as it is not supported in Hibernate 5.

**Update**
The client should have next JSON response model:

Label1
LabelSupplier1

Label1
LabelSupplier2

Label2
LabelSupplier3

Label2
LabelSupplier4

So, actually the Label should be duplicated for  LabelSupplier.
TBH I don't know how to map Hibernate this way efficiently.

Comment: Actually, I need to return the next resource model for the client:
LabelResource {
LabelSuppliersResource - // not a single entity in the list.
}
Additionally, I should allow for a null LabelSuppliersResource. If I use findAll(Pageable) on the LabelSuppliersRepository, it will perform an inner join, which may not return all LabelResource objects.

Comment: Updated a question a bit.

Comment: The relation should be lazy. Also please use ac tual classes and types in your question as we are now again reasoning about different types.

Comment: @M.Deinum well, I am using criteria API as I mentioned in my initial problem description. Let's assume I can use `findAll(@Nullable Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable)` from LabelSupplier repo for that. By my requirements I need still return Label if it doesn't contain any LabelSuppliers. (So this won't work for me as under the hood will be INNER JOIN(LEFT JOIN) on labelSupplier - Label)

Comment: Let's say I am able to utilize the `findAll(@Nullable Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable)` method from the `Label` repository. The `Label` class contains a collection of `LabelSupplier` objects. However, I am unable to establish a one-to-one relationship in this scenario. If I were to use a custom mapper, I would have to duplicate the code for each `LabelSupplier` under its parent `Label`. This may cause issues with pagination and offset. (This will not work because COUNTER will be incorrect and OFFSET could be incorrect as well)

Comment: @M.Deinum “As stated use the LabelSupplierRepository order on the Label” could you clarify what do you mean by that? For me is not obvious. Thanks.

Comment: It means if I will use Label repo and I will use lets say page 1 and size 10 I can not predict how many suppliers will be exist on this first page. But  client will expect exactly 10 suppliers.

Comment: “Exactly as I stated. findAllOrderByLabelName(Pageable) (or whatever you want to order it by). Which should include the null Label as well. You will never get the LabelSupplier without the Label through the LabelRepository as that will only be navigable if there is a relation” - than how will I duplicate each label for label supplier?

Comment: @M.Deinum how the Order By will resolve problem for 1 - 1 mapping?

Comment: @M.Deinum You are suggesting the solution that won't work for me from the start. TBH. So, please read my initial message here.